# Java Calendar: Why are UTC offsets being reversed?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to grok time-handling, and I've stumbled upon something in Java that has me somewhat baffled. Take this sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Calendar set to 12:00 AM of the current day (Eastern Daylight Time)
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4"));
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    /////

    //Calendar set to 12:00 AM of the current day (UTC time)
    Calendar utcCal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    utcCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    utcCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    utcCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    utcCal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    /////

    long oneHourMilliseconds = 3600000;
    System.out.println((cal.getTimeInMillis() - utcCal.getTimeInMillis()) / oneHourMilliseconds);
}
```

I visualize the algorithm for calculating the time represented by `cal` taking 1 of 2 forms:

1. Calculate the number of milliseconds from the Epoch, add offset (add -4)
2. Calculate the number of milliseconds from  (Epoch + offset). So # of milliseconds from (`Epoch - 4 * oneHourMilliseconds`).

Both of these algorithms should yield a result that is 4 hours behind that of `utcCal`, however running the code returns `4` .

Can someone explain to me why `cal`, despite being set to a time zone 4 hours *behind* that of `utcCal`, ends up having a millisecond value 4 hours after that of *utcCal*? Shouldn't the code be returning `-4`?

Comment: 8 pm EDT = 12 am GMT.  12 am EDT = 4 am GMT.  There is a plus four hours difference between the two 12 am times.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an unfortunate piece of history. A time zone with an ID of "GMT-4" is what you'd *expect* to be "UTC+4", i.e. it's 4 hours *ahead* of UTC.

From the etcetera file from tzdb:

```
# We use POSIX-style signs in the Zone names and the output abbreviations,
# even though this is the opposite of what many people expect.
# POSIX has positive signs west of Greenwich, but many people expect
# positive signs east of Greenwich.  For example, TZ='Etc/GMT+4' uses
# the abbreviation "GMT+4" and corresponds to 4 hours behind UTC
# (i.e. west of Greenwich) even though many people would expect it to
# mean 4 hours ahead of UTC (i.e. east of Greenwich).
```

And from [this similar explanation](http://labs.hoffmanlabs.com/node/120):

> If you can at all manage it, *avoid definitions and use of the GMT timezones...*

Answer (score 2):

The calendar `cal` is set to `2012-04-18 00:00:00` of the timezone `GMT-4`.

That moment corresponds to `2012-04-18 04:00:00` in `UTC` (in other words, when it's 12 AM in the timezone `GMT-4`, it's 4 AM in `UTC`).

The calendar `utcCal` is set to `2012-04-18 00:00:00` of the timezone `UTC`.

The difference between `2012-04-18 04:00:00` and `2012-04-18 00:00:00` is 4 hours, so you see 4 being printed.

Answer (score 0):

The other Answers are correct. In various contexts the `+`/`-` of offset-from-UTC values have opposite meanings.

## java.time

In the context of modern *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later:

- Ahead of UTC, `+`
- Behind UTC, `-`

So the offset currently used in India (`Asia/Kolkata`) is `+05:30`, five and a half hours ahead of UTC. In the `America/Regina` zone of Canada, the offset currently used is `-06:00`, six hours behind UTC.

### Use zones, not offsets

The big tip here is to **always use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)** rather than a mere offset, whenever known.

An [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is simply a number of hours, minutes, and seconds; nothing more, nothing less. A [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a certain region. So a zone is always preferable to an offset.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
```

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

For four hours ahead of UTC, use a time zone such as `Asia/Dubai`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( `Asia/Dubai` ) ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2018-03-01T02:39:18.801642+04:00[Asia/Dubai]

For four hours behind UTC, use a time zone such as `America/Blanc-Sablon`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( `America/Blanc-Sablon` ) ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2018-02-28T18:39:18.801642-04:00[America/Blanc-Sablon]

### `ZoneOffset`

If you are not certain of the intended time zone, and have only an offset-from-UTC, use `ZoneOffset` class.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes( 4 , 30 ) ; // Positive hours is ahead of UTC (east), while negative hours is behind UTC (west).
```

For UTC itself (an offset of zero), use the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).